# Why is SynchronizationContext.Current null?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

Error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

The algorithm below works.
I tried it, then I removed the `Winform` project to another directory and `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`.
Why?

```
SynchronizationContext uiCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;  

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int[] makeSelfMoves = new int[4];

    lock (replay)
    {
        // count should be more than 2
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int[]> item in replay)
        {              
            makeSelfMoves = replay[item.Key];
            codeFile.ExecuteAll(makeSelfMoves[0],
              makeSelfMoves[1], makeSelfMoves[2], makeSelfMoves[3]);

            // i get the error here. uictx is null
            uiCtx.Post(o =>
            {
                PrintPieces(codeFile.PieceState());
            }, null);                               

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What context *are* you running this code in then? A console app?

Comment: And what's creating an instance of this object and when? (You seem to be capturing the synchronization context *on construction* after all.)

Comment: I wonder if delaying the capture is all that is required here

Comment: The instance is being created with the application being run.. The post is triggered with a button press and a reply of the chess game should be shown

Comment: Marc, do you mean using this method: SetWaitNotificationRequired

Comment: it is on the backgroundworker

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your code critically depends on exactly when and where the constructor of your class runs.  SynchronizationContext.Current will be null when:

- your class object is created too soon, before your code creates an instance of the Form class or calls Application.Run() in Main().  That's when the Current member is set to an instance of WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext, the class that knows how to marshal calls with the message loop.  Fix this by moving your object instancing code to the main form constructor.
- your class object is created on any thread other than the main UI thread.  Only the UI thread in a Winforms application can marshal calls.  Diagnose this by adding a constructor to your class with this statement:

  ```
    Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
  ```

Also add this line to the Main() method in Program.cs.  It won't work if the displayed value in the Output window is different.  Fix this by moving your object instancing code to, again, the main form constructor so you can be sure it runs on the UI thread.

Comment: alright , i will keep your point in mind..thanks for the help

Comment: This is an old answer, but its worth noting that Application.Run is not the only time WinForms installs its SynchronizationContext. I have found that creating a new Form also results in the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext being installed, and presumably the constructors of other Control subclasses would have the same effect, though I have not tested this.

Comment: I've got an application in which I actually have just `new Control();` as a statement all by itself with a comment stating that this is done because I need a synchronisation context earlier than it would otherwise be created.

Comment: It is the Control class constructor that calls WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.InstallIfNeeded.  Not so sure I want to document that :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when creating WinForms via dependency injection in my test framework.  Originally I would capture the SynchronizationContext.Current in my constructor:

```
private readonly SynchronizationContext UISyncCtxt;

public MyWinFormViewModel ()
{
    UISyncCtxt = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    ...
}
```

This worked fine if this MyWinFormViewModel was created while an application was already running, but this isn't necessarily the situation when creating the dependency graph in the test harness.  When created by the test harness, SynchronizationContext.Current would be null, and there'd be a null reference exception later.

My solution was to "lazily" evaluate it as follows:

```
    private SynchronizationContext _uisyncctxt;

    private SynchronizationContext UISyncCtxt => 
        _uisyncctxt ??= SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

By the time I actually need the context (to update controls on the form), it's assured to be present (because the form has been instantiated).

EDIT:  Peter Duniho brought up a valid point about arbitrarily grabbing the synchronization context.  My original answer also makes this class dishonest about its dependencies since it relies on this context, but doesn't request it through the constructor or other injectable method.  Since this class uses DI, I added a dependency called IUISyncContext, which has the following signature:

```
public interface IUISyncContext
{
    SynchronizationContext UISyncContext { get; }
}
```

...and the constructor for my view model:

```
private readonly SynchronizationContext UISyncCtxt;

public MyWinFormViewModel (IUISyncContext syncContext)
{        
    UISyncCtxt = syncContext.UISyncContext;
    ...
}
```

Thanks for the feedback, Peter.

Comment: Except now you still have to remember to only access the context after it exists, _and_ you have to make sure you only access it from the thread where you care about it. This doesn't improve on the accepted answer, and in fact is a lot worse.

Comment: Interesting points.  But, I suppose you have bigger problems if you end up in a situation where you're trying to acquire the UI thread context and you haven't been given an opportunity to get it, yet.  

I'd actually considered writing an injectable service that captures the context, but thought that seemed like a heavy handed solution.  

What's your recommended solution to this problem?

Comment: After considering this further, I do believe using an injectable service would be the better solution, since technically its a dependency this class takes.  By grabbing it arbitrarily in this manner, the class isn't being honest about its dependencies.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: _"What's your recommended solution to this problem?"_ -- there is no one-size-fits all solution. In the modern API, the sync context almost never needs to be acquired explicitly. Between binding engines and async/await handling this stuff automatically, it's just not an issue. I would not recommend DI as a _general purpose_ approach, because most code doesn't even use DI and trying to explain it to someone who doesn't already know how to deal with their sync context is an uphill battle, not to mention just takes the one problem they already have and creates a second one from it.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you feel that you have a _novel_ problem related to dealing with the sync context, where a new answer is warranted, posting the answer here isn't the right approach. You're not adding anything useful to the _question_ that was asked here. Instead, consider posting your own question that outlines the _specific and novel_ scenario you are dealing with, and posting a self-answer to that question. Naturally, make sure the question really is novel...there may already be one or more questions on the site specifically dealing with your type of scenario (i.e. with DI).

Comment: My application is using a Windows Form "View", so the controls must be updated in the UI thread's context.  I could certainly argue this is a responsibility of the View, rather than a ViewModel class, though.  E.g. the binding methods in the View could acquire the context on their own rather than the View Model concerning itself with it.

Comment: Someone looking for a DI-specific solution is going to have a hard time finding such an answer buried under this question, but if you post a good question to go along with your answer, you can make the answer itself much more discoverable. That helps everyone.

Comment: _"I could certainly argue this is a responsibility of the View"_ -- yes, one could argue that. It's not a bad philosophy, and is consistent with the way WPF handles it (i.e. where the binding engine itself automatically marshals to the UI thread). It's unfortunate that the Winforms binding features don't handle this automatically.