Resource Dictionary for ToggleSwitch custom control not loading
I wanted to style the checkbox on a WPF window (used as a form in a VSTO Excel addin) like an iOS switch. I found some code here and made a few adjustments.
I'll be adding a class to manage a few properties but before I do that I wanted to be able to use it also on other WPF windows for the same solution (and perhaps other applications). I placed my ToggleSwitch.xaml in a folder named Controls then created another folder named Themes where I place the Generic.xaml below
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/VSTOApp;component/Controls/ToggleSwitch.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    
</ResourceDictionary>

Finally, in AssemblyInfo.cs I added these
using System.Windows;

[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,            //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
                                                //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                                // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly   //where the generic resource dictionary is located
                                                //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                                // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]

This way I shouldn't have to add on every window
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ToggleSwitch.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

And I have ToggleSwitch.xaml in the same folder where the WPF windows are.
However, when I drop a checkbox on the window the style defined in ToggleSwitch.xaml does not apply. Any idea why the Resource Dictionary would not load?
I try testing the same in a WpfApp, doing the same steps I did for the VSTO addin solution, but the results were the same.

A checkbox isn't a custom control. You can define a template target type checkbox with a key and apply using staticresource. Put it in a resource dictionary and merge that in app.xaml so you can use throughout the app.

Thank for clarifying that Andy. I do not have an App.xaml in my VSTO addin. I know I could do that and add merge the resource dictionary in every form (WPF window). I was hoping there was a way to merge the resource dictionary in one place and not having to do that in every form (WPF window)

Why do you call CheckBox a toggle switch? 90% of people that use WPF will know check box. You didn't share your xaml for either where you are using it and how your style is defined. There could be a spelling mistake or you didn't specify {x:Type CheckBox}.

there is a link in the description where the xaml for styling the checkbox is and it works

If you have multiple windows then you can instantiate an application object and merge resources into it's resources.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165610/running-wpf-application-from-excel-vsto-and-win-form
